# Question regarding db.collection('cafes').orderBy('city').onSnapshot()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I know that if I'm using Firestore, I can use the command:

```
db.collection('cafes').orderBy('city').onSnapshot()
```

to set them in order but my actual question is: Does this code only work if I'm using Firestore?? or is this code actually from JavaScript language itself so that I can use this code even when I'm not even using Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you have a `db` object... That is where the answer to your question is.

what is the value of `db`? probably you are seeing [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) but you probably want to check [this first](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

it says something like:

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
```

so your `db` is an instance of `firebase.firestore()` therefore it is not accessible outside that context or as you refer as `from javascript language` :)

Hope this helps.